# How to make SonarQube use SonarXML checks in a Java project

Tags: java, gradle, xpath, sonarqube

I am using Sonarqube to check my Java project. I have some xml files under src/main/resources.
I already created some XPath rules I want, but I do not know how to tell sonar to use them on those files.
When I check the Code tab on the project, the resources folder is not included.
And when I run a scan those files are not included.